# Putting two variables into the same table's Field

Tags: php, html, sql

I have two textboxes in HTML and I want to join them into the same field in sql.

Those two textboxes where I have my cursor are the zip code ($zip and $zip2): https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMqFI.png and I and to put them together on the same place in my sql table:

I'm inserting the values like this:

```
$insere="INSERT INTO Perfil VALUES ('".$nome."','".$apelido."','".$dataNasc."','".$sex."','".$PLSHELPME."','".$morada."','".$username."')";
```

How can i do this ?

Is it `$zip+$zip2` or what ?

As asked by Typoheads:

```
<?php
        $username=$_POST['username'];
        $password=$_POST['password'];
        $email=$_POST['email'];
        $nome=$_POST['nome'];
        $apelido=$_POST['apelido'];
        $dataNasc=$_POST['dataNasc'];
        $sex=$_POST['sex'];
        $zip=$_POST['zip'];
        $zip2=$_POST['zip2'];
        $morada=$_POST['morada'];
        echo '<h2>Registado:</h2>';
        echo 'Bemvindo '.$nome.' '.$apelido.' aka '.$username.'.';
        $conexao=mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
        if (!$conexao)
            {
            echo 'falha na ligação,<br>';
            echo mysql_error();
            }
        mysql_select_db("alienstore",$conexao);
        $insere="INSERT INTO Perfil VALUES ('".$nome."',
                                            '".$apelido."',
                                            '".$dataNasc."',
                                            '".$sex."',
                                            '".$zip . $zip2."',
                                            '".$morada."',
                                            '".$username."')";
        $resultado=mysql_query($insere);
        if($resultado==1)
            {
            echo "<br><b>Registado</b>";
            }
        else
            "<br><b>Erro, não registado</b>";
        mysql_close($conexao);
        }
    ?>
```

Ok now I got a new problem... that has nothing to do with the previous one: it all goes well without errors, but it seems that it isn't inserting to the table the right way. I checked the database and there was no data that I inserted.. Does anyone know any usual problems or erros that people do so I can check it on my code/programs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP you use the `.` to concatenate string values:

```
$insere = "INSERT INTO Perfil VALUES (
    '".$nome."',
    '".$apelido."',
    '".$dataNasc."',
    '".$sex."',
    '".$zip1 . $zip2."',
    '".$morada."',
    '".$username."'
)";
```

Comment: It doesn't work...

"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in C:\xampp\htdocs\1\registar.php on line 30" Which is exactly this line.

Comment: This code works fine. Maybe you have copied it wrong? Show us your code, please